# Date picker only shows up after I submit my form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app and their is an input area where a user clicks the text field and a pop-up date picker pops up they then choose the date and it writes it in the text_field. Am using [this](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) jquery date picker plugin, The problem I can't figure out am having is if I click on the text field the date picker doesn't pop up but when I leave it blank and click submit then the errors show that it must be filled and when i click on it then it works, simply put it only pop up after i click submit and get errors?

input field page with the plugin:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
<center><h1> New deadline </h1></center>
<%= simple_form_for(@deadline, url: deadlines_path, html: { class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%=f.input :title %>
  <%=f.input :date,  input_html: {:id => "datetimepicker4"}%>
  <%= f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: {rows: "6"} %>


  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>

<%= link_to "Back", deadlines_path, :class =>'btn btn-primary'  %>

</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script>
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  lang:'ru'
});
$('#image_button').click(function(){
  $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker('show'); //support hide,show and destroy command
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you forget about dev console F12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have few suggestions

1) First include `<script></script>` tags in `<head>` section always.
2) As you need the script to run after DOM has loaded completely and following rails standards place the below code in separate 'example.js' file in assets/javascripts folder.
3) Include the javascript in your view code using <%= javascript_include_tag "example" %> {to call javascript}.

4) I am not sure but try updating `$('#datetimepicker4')` with `$('input.datepicker')`and try changing the 'input_html: {:id => "datetimepicker4"}' to `input_html: {:id => "datepicker"}`